# The $ 1 \operatorname{ mod } \mathfrak{m}$ congruence relation in ray $ P^{\mathfrak{m}}$ of the ideal theoretic ray class group

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

Let $K$ be a number field, $\mathcal{O}_K$ its ring of integers and $S$ a
subset of the real places. Let $\mathfrak{m} \subset \mathcal{O}_K$ an ideal. The ideal
theoretic
*ray class group* of $\mathfrak{m} $ and $S$ is the quotient group

$$ I^{\mathfrak{m}}/P^{\mathfrak{m}}  $$

where $ I^{\mathfrak{m}} $ is the group of fractional ideals co-prime to $ \mathfrak{m} $,
and the "ray" $ P^{\mathfrak{m}}$ is the group
consisting of all principal ideals in the ring of integers of $K$ having the form $( \alpha)$
where $ \alpha $ is multiplicatively congruent to $ 1 \operatorname{ mod } \mathfrak{m}$
such that $\alpha $ are positive at the places of $S$.

Could somebody explain the original motivation for imposing for elements of
the "ray" $ P^{\mathfrak{m}}$ this rather exotic congruence condition for the elements $\alpha $ to be
congruent to $ 1 \operatorname{ mod } \mathfrak{m}$?

I suppose that the name "ray" came from the assumption that these in addition should be
positive at the real places of $S$. This suggests these "behave" similar like the
positive reals $\mathbb{R}_{ \ge 0 }$, which can visualized geometrically as a "ray". I noticed that in [this discussion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/101725/what-is-the-ray-in-ray-class-group) the reason for the name "ray" was discussed, but that doesn't exactly address my issue, since as far as I understood the punch lines from there correctly, the name "ray" based on the positivity assumption for *real places*.

But I would like to understand the reason for the condition $ 1 \operatorname{ mod } \mathfrak{m}$ for *finite places/ primes*, which looks very obscure to me
and seemingly falls unexpectedly from the sky.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gauß had studied classes of binary quadratic forms with arbitrary discriminant. Dedekind realized that the class groups of forms with fundamental discriminant are ideal class groups (in the strict sense) of quadratic number fields. In order to find something similar for forms with discriminant $\Delta = df^2$, where $d$ is a fundamental discriminant, it was necessary to put conditions modulo $f$ on the generators of principal ideals.

After Hilbert had realized that unramified abelian extensions were class fields in the sense that the splitting of prime ideals is governed by their order in the class groups, it was only natural to try and incorporate ramified abelian extensions. The simplest such extensions are cyclotomic extensions of the rationals, and their Galois groups are subgroups of $({\mathbb Z}/m{\mathbb Z})^\times$. The splitting of primes $p$ depends on their behavior modulo $m$, and so it is quite natural to look for a generalized ideal class group that realizes such residue class groups. Again, this could have been looked up in Gauss's Disquisitiones: He showed that the class group of primitive quadratic forms with discriminant $\Delta = m^2$ is isomorphic to $({\mathbb Z}/m{\mathbb Z})^\times$.

What I'm trying to say is that this "exotic condition" is a very natural one for everyone familiar with Gauss's theory of binary quadratic forms and Dedekind's explanation of these groups in terms of ideal classes in orders.

Comment: what do you mean by "class group of forms"? (I have to admit that I never heard about this terminology before :(  My naive guess: is it where you take the set of quadratic forms and mod out certain relation, ie in similar flavour like for the Witt groups. Or do you mean by to class groups of forms something different?

Comment: Equivalence classes (with respect to SL$_2({\mathbb Z})$) of primitive binary quadratic forms with discriminant $\Delta$ form a group with respect to composition. See e.g. https://mast.queensu.ca/~frseguin/BQFarticle.pdf

Comment: Alright. So in summary this condition $1 \operatorname{ mod } \mathfrak{m}$
really arosed exclusively 
from the -let me call it "presidential case" -$\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)/\mathbb{Q}$? 
In short: 
one was looking for generalization of the concept "class fields" to 
ramified abelian extensions. Hilbert's unramified class fields are 
characterized by the property that their Galois group is isomorphic 
to "usual" ideal class group. And the aim of the generalzation to 
ramified case was based on the idea to replace the "usual"
ideal class group $Cl(K)=I/P$ by something structurally similar,

Comment: say $I′/P′$ such that this quotient group is isomorphic to the Galois group as
in unramified case. 
Then, one analyzed explicitely the case $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)/\mathbb{Q}$ and 
deduced that $I^m/P^m$ as 
defined above with this "strange" $1 \operatorname{ mod } \mathfrak{m}$ condition
did exactly the job and so was exactly the "right" 
replacement of the usual class group for $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)/\mathbb{Q}$ 
in order to retain the 
isomorphism with the Galois group.

Comment: And then one just literally copied one-to-one this $ I^m/P^m$ with
$P^m$ defined by this congruence relation and imposed 
it formally as definition of ray class group for arbitrary fields $K$? 
 So one observed that was the "right" definition for a special case 
and imposed it as general definition, and that's it? Or is there something "deeper" going on behind this $1 \operatorname{ mod } \mathfrak{m} $ condition ?

Comment: Hilbert came after Weber had defined his "number groups" in "Ueber Zahlengruppen in algebraischen Körpern" (https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01447919.pdf). But Hilbert class fields were known in connection with the theory of complex multiplication.

Comment: in this paper Weber does not seem to attatch any central importance to the ray (which he called there the "symbolische Convergenz" on page 447) , but to use it more or less as an auxiliary construction to calculate indices of certain subgroups. So far I know it was Weber who invented & defined the ray class group in this way as quotient $I^m/P^m$. Is the paper you linked the first one among Weber's works where this notation of congruence group of $ 1 \operatorname{ mod } \mathfrak{m}$ elements was explicitly introduced? I'm still wondering because the way he talks about it in the paper

Comment: suggests that he regards it as a well known object, not something brand new, as if he had already worked with it before.

Comment: I still have another question: so far I see til now Weber's 
main motivation to define the ray ideal $P^m$ in the way
he did comes primary from analysis of isomorphism
$ ({\mathbb Z}/m{\mathbb Z})^\times \cong 
\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)/\mathbb{Q}) $ and the attempt
to mimic it formally to other fields to establish 
his generalization of class fields. You mentioned that 
 theory of complex multiplication were known at that time
(to Weber?).

Comment: Do you know if at the time Weber came 
with his ray class groups there was maybe another 
well understood concrete example of a ray class field
$L/K$ where $K$ is CM, eg $K= \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-d}), d >0$
with $\text{Gal}(L/K) \cong I^m_K/P^m_K$ which might encouraged 
him to define the ray class group 
he did besides considerations with the cyclotomic field mentioned above?
So say naturally next to 
$\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)/\mathbb{Q}$ on the difficulty scale.
Or in other words: Had also concrete considerations on CM fields influenced 
his definition of ray class groups?

Answer (score 3):

In short, because the multiplicative order in $\mathbb{O}_K/\mathfrak{m}$ is important. Consider the classical result that a prime $p$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ has inertial degree its multiplicative order mod $m$  and ramification index $\phi(p^k)$ for $p^k \vert \vert m$, in the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)/\mathbb{Q}$. Thus, to say that $p$ splits completely is exactly saying that $p\equiv 1$ mod $m$. In fact, this is exactly showing that $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)$ is the ray class field for the (strict) ray class group of $m\mathbb{Z}$.

Surely there are other flavours of explanation, but I like this intuition.

Comment: so in summary this congruence condition $1 \operatorname{ mod } \mathfrak{m}$ is coined by trying to naively 1-to-1 mimic this condition from the "presidential case" $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)/\mathbb{Q}$, where it indeed characterizes the splitting behavior?