# CM-fields and ideal theoretic ray class group

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

Let $K$ be a number field, $\mathcal{O}_K$ its ring of integers
and $S$ a finite subset of the real places. Let $\mathfrak{m} 
\subset \mathcal{O}_K$ an ideal. The ideal
theoretic
*ray class group* of $\mathfrak{m} $ and $S$ is the quotient group

$$ I^{\mathfrak{m}}/P^{\mathfrak{m}}  $$

where $ I^{\mathfrak{m}} $ is the group of fractional ideals co-prime to $ \mathfrak{m} $,
and the "ray" $ P^{\mathfrak{m}}$ is the group
consisting of all principal ideals in the ring of integers of $K$ having the form $( \alpha)$
where $ \alpha \in K^*$ is multiplicatively congruent to $ 1 \operatorname{ mod } \mathfrak{m}$
and that $\alpha $ are positive at all real places in $S$.

In [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/433105/the-1-operatorname-mod-mathfrakm-congruence-relation-in-ray-p-math/433118?noredirect=1#comment1115860_433118)  I asked about the origin of the motivation
to introduce ray class group in that way, especially the ray ideal
$P^{\mathfrak{m}} $ with it's at first glance strange
from heaven fallen congruence relation $1 \operatorname{ mod } \mathfrak{m}$.

Viewed retrospectively this approach provided the "right"
generalization of the ideal class group: the "ray class
group" $ I^{\mathfrak{m}}/P^{\mathfrak{m}}  $ provides the
analoga of the "classical" ideal class group
in the sense that
it carries roughly speaking the same amount of information
about finite abelian extensions of $K$ where the only primes
of $\mathcal{O}_K$ can ramify, which divide $\mathfrak{m}$
like the usual class group about all abelian finite unramified
extensions of $K$. But my qeustion deals with the origin only.

Thanks to excellent answers by Franz Lemmermeyer and
SomeCallMeTim of the linked question one can say in summary that Weber, who
introduced this notation, was presumingly inspired by methods
from Gauss's theory of binary quadratic forms and
Dedekind's explanation of these groups in terms of ideal classes
in orders, and the "presidential case"
$\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)/\mathbb{Q}$ where the Galois group
$({\mathbb Z}/m{\mathbb Z})^\times$ is exactly
$ I^{\mathfrak{m}}/P^{\mathfrak{m}} $ in terms of this new terminology and
where the the primes $p$ which split completely are exactly those satisfing the relation $p \equiv 1 \operatorname{ mod } \mathfrak{m}$. So $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)/\mathbb{Q}$ seems to be the "perfectly fitted" inspiration for the definition of ray class group.

My *question* is if $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)/\mathbb{Q}$
is really the only one concrete example paved to Weber the way
for the definition of the ray class group
$ I^{\mathfrak{m}}/P^{\mathfrak{m}}  $ he did or were at that time to Weber
also known some concrete examples of *CM-fields* ( ... say naturally next to the cyclotomic field on the difficulty scale),
eg of form $K= \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-d}), d >0$ with known Galois
groups isomorphic to $ \cong I^m_K/P^m_K $ and well understood splitting behavior of primes based on the congruence relation from above, which also
inspired him to define the ray class group in the way he did it?

The reason why I asking is that I'm pretty sure that at that time ($\sim 1896$ ) the CM-fields ware known and provided a widely active research field - keyword Kronecker's Jugendtraum for imaginary quadratic field -  so I'm wondering if these might be also influenced Weber in his definition of ray class group besides the cyclotomic field only.

Comment: Vol III of Weber's Algebra deals with elliptic functions, number fields, and the theory of complex multiplication as far as it was known back then.